# use of bash env variable in post section of pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have been reading as many posts as possible about this topic but none of them suggest working solutions for me, so, throwing it again to the community:

In a Jenkinsfile pipeline I have

```
steps {
  (...)
  sh script: '''
    $pkgname #existing var
    export report_filename=$pkgname'_report.txt'
    (stuff is being written to the $report_filename file...)
  '''
}
post {
 always {
  script {
    //want to read the file with name carried by $report_filename
    def report = readFile(file: env.report_filename, encoding: 'utf-8').trim()
    buildDescription(report)
  }
 }
}
```

I don't manage to pass the value of the report_filename bash var on to the post > always > script section. Tried ${env.report_filename} (with/without single/double quotes), with/without env. and some other crazy things.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect `$pkgname` on the first line of the shell script to do? What does the variable contain?

Comment: `export` makes the variable available to *children* of the shell, not to the parent.

Comment: the variable $pkgname captures the name of a conda package I just built (in the "step" section). I then build the string {name_of_conda_package}_report.txt and want to store it in the var report to be used in the post condition.

Comment: So just `$pkgname` would produce `condapackage.zip: no such file or directory` if the variable contains `condapackage.zip`.

Comment: $pkgname contains a string, like 'a-b-c', I build a report name 'a-b-c_report.txt' via the report_filename assignment and I want to use the report_filename var in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

May by it little bit not right.

1. create variable def var
2. use options returnStdout: true. And parse output. var = sh ( script " echo  #existing var", returnStdout: true).split("\n")
3. use var[0] in stage readFile(file: var[0]...)

If u can use env, add:

```
environment {
    VAR = sh (script " echo  #existing var", returnStdout: true).split("\n") [0]
}
script {
    //want to read the file with name carried by $report_filename
    def report = readFile(file: env.VAR , encoding: 'utf-8').trim()
    buildDescription(report)
}
```

Comment: Would it not be a lot easier to define the variable in the Jenkinsfile and not have the shell `echo` it back to you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you don't simply declare the variables in Groovy right at the start.

I'm not too familiar with the language, and don't currently have a way to test this; but something like this:

```
def pkgname = "gunk"
def report_filename = "${pkgname}_report.txt"
steps {
  (...)
  sh script: """
    # use triple double quotes so that Groovy variables are interpolated
    # $pkgname #syntax error, take it out
    (stuff is being written to the $report_filename file...)
  """
}
post {
 always {
  script {
    //want to read the file with name carried by $report_filename
    def report = readFile(file: env.report_filename, encoding: 'utf-8').trim()
    buildDescription(report)
  }
 }
}
```